# custom rows in react-admin list view

Tags: datagrid, react-admin

I am using the [react-admin list component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html) and want to add a custom layout for specific rows.

Usually, each row is build by the list component using the data from the data-provider. I would like to customize specific rows based on the data of the row. These specific rows should not use the standard layout (and columns), but a specially defined one.

Here is a example, what I am looking for:
[image]

The special rows should be selected according to the data object.
Standard data object, which forms a standard row, may look like:

```
{ 
    id: 127,
    Reference: "OEPEE4",
    author_id: 12,
    ...
}
```

The special entry may look like:

```
{
    id: 128,
    isSpecial: true,
    text: "Lorem Ipsum ...",
    ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Hendrik, could you provide a visual example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @AxelJunes, I have added an image!

Comment: Ok, I see. How does the data that you want to display look like? What I mean is how do you know which rows should have a custom layout?

Comment: I have not designed the interface yet. However, I was thinking of special object fields. I add this to the question.

Comment: @AxelJunes: I have added the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key lies in creating your custom `DataGrid` component's body and rows, because that way you would be able to check the value of `record.isSpecial`, as the `record` is passed to the component. Take a look at [this part of the docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-datagrid-component).

I tried playing around a bit with a custom `DataGridRow` (here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-edit-in-list-06lu5)), and I was able to display only the text when the record has the `isSpecial` property, although I think you would need to style the cells and the row. Maybe you get some ideas from it. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @AxelJunes. This is what I was thinking of. :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped. Could you mark the solution as the valid answer?

Comment: Sure, clicked on useful instead of answer some minutes ago. ;)